# F# replace first element in list?

Tags: list, f#, replace, element

Hey, I'm trying to learn some f# basics and am stumbling along.  I'm wondering how you would go about "replacing" the first element in a list.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you have to use list? This is natural for using array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could 'cons' (using the `::`-operator) the new first element to the tail (`List.tail`) of the original list:

```
let theList = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let firstReplaced = 0 :: (List.tail a)
```

Note that this will leave the original list (`theList`) untouched.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I figured that out just after I asked, but wasn't sure if that was the cleanest way

Answer (score 4):

Here's a general purpose function.  It will replace the head of a list with a new value if the list is non-empty, else it will return a single element list with the replace value.

```
let replaceHead newHead list = 
  match list with
  | _ :: tail -> newHead :: tail
  | [] -> [newHead]
```

Comment: This doesn't really make for very exciting golf `let r h=function|_::t->h::t|[]->[h]`

Comment: @gradbot my golf game is terrible ;)